# Windows Security Prompt Rust

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo, windows-security

Every time I run a rust file, windows ask me to send a sample with the executable, is that normal if yes how to disable it, I've never seen this problem and I disabled the "Automatic Sample Submission"

I tried to change the UAC but didn't work.

Comment: Can you add a [security exclusion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26) to your Rust dev directory?

Comment: there is no other definitive way ?

Comment: I'm sure there's more than one way, but that could work. What's wrong with that?

Comment: just asking so its normal to have this alert ?

Comment: If Windows is being super paranoid about unknown executables, for sure! Many trivial Rust programs flag the virus scanner since they contain significant components of "known bad" samples, but that's mostly because the boilerplate itself gets tagged. It's silly, but as you add more code, your program becomes more distinct and less likely to get flagged. The alternative is to disable scanning for your work directory.